# Command Line: '■c' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: vba, command-line

I am creating a simple batch file using VBA (Fileout) within an AccessDB.  The file is created and contains the desired commands, but when I attempt to run the Batch file from within code or at the Command Line, I get the following error:

`C:\Test>■c
'■c' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Here is the basic idea of the code I am using to create the batch file. << commands >> are replaced for purposes of this example:

```
Dim strCmd As String
Dim strBatchFile As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim Fileout As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strBatchFile = "C:\Test\FTP_Test.bat"

Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(strBatchFile, True, True)
    strCmd = <<command 1>> & vbCrLf
    strCmd = strCmd & <<command 2>>
Fileout.Write strCmd

Fileout.Close

Shell strBatchFile

End Sub
```

From VBA can I specify some other filetype?

Comment: `fso.CreateTextFile(strBatchFile, True, False)`. You're writing unicode.

Comment: Comintern - thanks!  Easy enough to fix.